# Only *some* private github repositories visible on google colab

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I've checked the box on google colab "Include private repos", but not all of my private repos are visible for opening (this is at https://colab.research.google.com/github/ btw).

Strangely, only the one that I'm currently trying to open is unavailable!

Comparing this repo to another private repo that is also private but is available, I don't see any clear indicators that they're different.

All my private repos are forked from other github users, but there's another I've forked from the same user that is visible.

Any suggestions?